# php_ibm_db2.dll extension for PHP7 on Windows?

Tags: php, dll, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I'm having a hard time finding a `php_ibm_db2.dll` extension for PHP7 on Windows.  The most recent version on https://pecl.php.net/package/ibm_db2 is from April 2016, so naturally it doesn't work.  I've tried downloading a trial of Zend Server 9.1 and using the bundled `php_ibm_db2.dll` file in a non Zend Server WAMP stack, but no luck (both for 32 and 64 bit versions).

Has anyone successfully connected to a remote IBM DB2 instance from a non Zend Server WAMP stack using PHP7 and the `db2_*()` functions?  If so, any advise/suggestions?

Note*: DB2 connect is installed, configured and connecting fine on the Windows machine I'm working on.  I would imagine ODBC via PHP would work as well, but I need to use the `db2_*()` functions to connect.

Comment: On pecl.php.net ther most recent ibm_db2 extension is 1.9.9, and it has a note that the latest update added PHP 7 support. You can even download a DLL.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy Where do you see the download for the DLL for PHP 7?  I only see the downloads for the DLL for 5.5 and 5.6.  I've tried using the 5.6 DLL (both TS and NTS) but I get error messages on startup saying it cannot read the file.

Comment: Maybe you have to compile it, but I can't even find the source for 1.9.9, it all seems to point to 1.9.7. Seems the pecl web site is incorrect.

Comment: I've received on good word that the source code for v1.9.9 (https://pecl.php.net/get/ibm_db2-1.9.9.tgz) can be used for PHP7.  Now I should just have to compile it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pecl repository isn't compiling the dlls anymore, the latest is 1.9.9 for php 5.6 :(

I compiled to myself the ibm_db2 2.0.5 for php 7.1.17

Remember: Install Ibm db2 ds drivers an add {ds_drivers_instalation_dir}/bin to Path env variable.

Comment: Thanks,  I no longer have a valid license for DB2 Connect to test. 
 However, it definitely seems it is up to us to compile the source ourselves so I'm marking this as the answer.

Comment: "php_ibm_db2.dll" is not a valid win32 application, I'm using Windows 10 64bits and PHP 7.2.2.

Comment: How and from where do I install ` Install Ibm db2 ds drivers` ?

Answer (score 2):

PECL is not generating DLLs from 7.x hence we have generated DLLs for all 7.x version and uploaded same in github directory. So any user can download specific version DLLs from link as per their requirement and can use it.

1) Download the php_ibm_db2 DLLs for PHP 7.x(7.0, 7.1, 7.2) from below link.
      https://github.com/ibmdb/php_ibm_db2
As of now (x64) DLLs for PHP 7.2 and PHP 7.3 are available. We will upload x86 DLLs soon.

2) For PHP 5.x, Download the DLL from Pecl itself. Pasted the link below.
      https://pecl.php.net/package/ibm_db2

Blog to install and compile PHP ibm_db2 for Linux and windows is pasted below.
   https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/96960515-2ea1-4391-8170-b0515d08e4da/entry/Install_PHP_ibm_db2_Driver?lang=en

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: It's a excellent contribution! Congratulations