# php_ibm_db2.dll extension for PHP7.2 available for windows?

Tags: php, dll, db2

Has anybody managed to compile the `php_ibm_db2.dll (ver 2.0.5)` for `Php7.2` on `windows (x86 & x64)`?

This Question is related to [How do I compile ibm_db2 tar for PHP 7 on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47918147/how-do-i-compile-ibm-db2-tar-for-php-7-on-windows) and [php_ibm_db2.dll extension for PHP7 on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440812/php-ibm-db2-dll-extension-for-php7-on-windows)

There is already a compiled `php_ibm_db2.dll` available for `Php7.1`, but not `Php7.2` and I couldn't find any official or unofficial website/link/source

edit: thanks to @mao I managed to compile the dll and it seems to be working fine, I uploaded the `php_ibm_db2-2.0.5-php7.2.6-ts-vc15-x86.zip` here https://mega.nz/#!D8k2UCRB!indvDsREa5A6KfKkOugNHmBNyOFO5dZ5tQttxGdXh_M

Comment: What have you tried so far? What has failed with which messages?

Comment: I followed this guide https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild_sdk_2 and extracted php-sdk-binary-tools to d:\php-sdk and invoked starter script phpsdk-vc15-x86.bat which gives error message "Could not determine 'vc15' directory" although I have VisuaStudio2017 installed

Comment: You get that error when the VC++ is either not installed or the relevant directories are not on the PATH.  Re-run the VS2017 setup tool and use its modify option to add "Desktop Development with C++" and the relvant Windows SDK.  Then close and reopen the command-prompt.

Comment: that worked, so I followed the guide and did a "configure --disable-all --enable-cli --with-ibm_db2" followed by nmake ... in the folder "Release_TS\pecl\ibm_db2-2.0.5" there now exist 3 files (ibm_db2.obj, ibm_db2.sbr and vc140.idb) ... how do I create the php_ibm_db2.dll ?

Comment: it worked by doing a "configure --disable-all --enable-cli --with-ibm_db2=shared"

Comment: To build ibm_db2 for Windows to match your built PHP , it seems you must use the phpize method (to make the dynamic link library) instead of the method you used which is for statically linked libraries.

Comment: To download php_ibm_db2 dll refer below link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440812/php-ibm-db2-dll-extension-for-php7-on-windows/55646469#55646469